# Простая процедура в MySql

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Здравствуйте! Помогите написать (да там и писать-то особо нечего) простейшую процедуру, чтобы она сохранилась, а не просто запрос. Есть таблица, нужно просто вытаскивать все поля...Что у меня не так? очень надо)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectPerson

BEGIN

 SELECT *

 FROM Person

END
```

Comment: Это называется хранимыми процедурами

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `SelectPerson` ()
LANGUAGE SQL         
DETERMINISTIC 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
COMMENT 'Some proc!' 
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM Person;

END
```

О написании хранимых процедур хорошо рассказывается **[здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=1189)**.

---

В **PHPMYADMIN** есть системная база данных - `mysql`. В ней хранятся различные параметры, в том числе и таблица с хранимыми процедурами - `proc`. Следовательно, чтобы получить все хранимые процедуры на сервере, надо выполнить такой запрос( имена процедур хранятся в поле `name`):

```
  SELECT name FROM mysql.proc
```

Comment: все равно ошибка(
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SelectPerson' () BEGIN SELECT * FROM Person END' at line 1

Comment: все равно не такие(((
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Comment: Пардон. Теперь все точно работает.

Comment: СПАСИБО Вам огромное! А подскажите еще где в phpmyAdmin можно как-то посмотреть, какие хранимые процедуры есть?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.